# Why does my Intellij Git plugin not commit files once I click commit?

Tags: git, version-control, intellij-idea, git-commit

Using IntelliJ 11.1.5, I was having trouble with committing my active changelist to my local Git repository.  When I would try to commit, I would observe that though the dialog would come up, clicking commit did nothing, and I would need to play with various configurations of unnecessary subchangelists, committing one file at a time, or unchecking the "optimize imports" and "code analysis" in order to get it to work.

Please note, that this was a somewhat random occurrence, and at other times this wouldn't be an issue.  In fact, when I switched to Git GUI or Git Bash the commits worked without incident.

So how do I fix things to be able to use the Git plugin?

Comment: 6 years later, I still experience this issue

Answer (score 27, accepted):

IntelliJ's staff suggested that I invalidate IntelliJ's caches.  (File->Invalidate Caches)  Every now and again, you should do this to clear out your local caches of Git/SVN to reduce bug occurrences.

Doing this resolved my problem and you should consider to do this, rather than trying to lean on the IDE's local history capabilities too heavily.

Answer (score 9):

I was experiencing problem with non-modal interface in version Ultimate 2020.3 and it turned-out I had to click on Commit button several time in order to work.

BTW, I've also did what @noisebelt suggested -> `Invalidate Cache and Restart` before switching to non-modal interface. To switch to that interface:

1. Go to `File > Settings > Version Control > Commit` (For Mac: `IntelliJ IDEA > Preferences > Version Control > Commit`)
2. Untick **Use non-modal commit interface** checkbox.
3. Good luck! :)

**UPDATE**:
You might want to un-check some of checkboxes in *Settings>Version Control>Commit* under "*Before Commit*" section such as Reformat Code, Rearrange Code, etc. and by doing that diagnose what might be causing this issue with committing.

Comment: `Non-modal commit interface` did work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A similar behaviour happens also in IntelliJ 2022.3 and the problem apparently may be caused by SonarLint failing to perform analyses, as [suggested in this discussion on JetBrains forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000020819-VCS-Commit-does-nothing). As a result the *Committing...* popup is shown indefinitely - with git command line working just fine.

Disabling SonarLing analysis (under `Settings -> Version Control -> Commit`) solved the problem and allowed me to commit files normally through IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the modal interface and I was trying alternatives. I found that unticking the checkbox for ***Analyze Code*** under ***File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Commit --Before commit*** section worked for me.